# Find Adress with housenumber like 17 1/2 with here-api

Tags: here-api

I tried the geocode api.
The results are very good and the scoring is nice.
But what about housenumbers like 17 1/2.
Is there a way to check against this housenumbers?
If I try Donauwörther Straße 17 1/2
I receive 17 as housenumber.
But the 17 1/2 exists.

Comment: I would suggest use this URL to check with full attributes - https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.xml?searchtext=1731+Pryor+Rd+SW+Unit+306,+Atlanta,+GA+30315&additionaldata=IncludeMicroPointAddresses,true&locationattributes=mapReference&gen=9&apiKey=your_api_key

Alternatively you can also check this example - https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/geocode-a-location-from-structured-address